# How to manage Rails database.yml

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, svn

What's the best way to handle the Rails database.yml if multiple people are working on the project and database locations are different (the socket in particular).

Comment: Clarification: I'd like this to work with Capistrano, which checks out from svn so I don't think ignore works.

Comment: I added two more steps for the Capistrano case.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

#### First, move `database.yml` to a template file.

If you're on Git:

```
git mv config/database.yml config/database.yml.example
git commit -m "moved database.yml to an example file"
```

Or, if you're on Subversion:

```
svn move config/database.yml config/database.yml.example
svn ci -m "moved database.yml to an example file"
```

#### Second, ignore the .yml version.

If you're on Git:

```
cat > .gitignore
config/database.yml

git add .gitignore
git commit -m "ignored database.yml"
```

If you're on Subversion:

```
svn propset svn:ignore config "database.yml"
```

#### Third, install [Where's your database.yml, dude?](http://github.com/technicalpickles/wheres-your-database-yml-dude):

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/technicalpickles/wheres-your-database-yml-dude
```

That plugin alerts developers before any Rake tasks are run if they haven't created their own local version of `config/database.yml`.

#### Fourth, set up a Capistrano deploy task:

```
# in RAILS_ROOT/config/deploy.rb:
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db'

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Symlinks the database.yml"
  task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
```

#### Fifth, upload the server's version of database.yml:

```
scp config/database.yml user@my_server.com:/path_to_rails_app/shared/config/database.yml
```

Comment: It is customary (though by no means required) to "accept" the answer you find the most helpful. I think you even get a badge for your first accept.

Comment: my bad - voted it up but didn't see the check. done and thank you!

Comment: I had to change after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db' to before 'deploy:assets:precompile', 'deploy:symlink_db' and then it worked.

Comment: Everything works, except for the fifth step. It says there's no such directory, but it's there.

Comment: Just an important note, I suggest using `cat >> .gitignore` instead.  Since you'll blow away your existing file otherwise...

Answer (score 16):

In Capistrano 3, instead of adding the new task, you can just do:

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the svn:ignore property to prevent that file from being versioned.

[Instructions here.](http://blog.bogojoker.com/2008/07/command-line-svnignore-a-file/)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method that uses capistrano an ERb to prompt for the credentials during deployment.

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/06/capistrano-and-database-yml/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers, I wrote a rake task similar to "Where's your database.yml, dude?", but allowing to keep template examples of any configuration file. Check it out: https://github.com/Velid/exemplify

As an alternative to writing separate production configs and linking them via Capistrano, I would also suggest using environment variables for your credentials:

```
password: <%= ENV['PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

There are a lot of [handy](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) [tools](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) and [ways](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/) to do this available around.