# Managing security for an open source rails 3 application stored at github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source, github, capistrano

New to rails, open source and soon ready for deploying to a production environment, I have some security considerations.

How to handle the database.yml is covered pretty good by, [how-to-manage-rails-database-yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449836/how-to-manage-rails-database-yml)

But from my point of view there are more configuration settings in a normal rails application that shouldn't be hosted in a public github repository and deployed to production e.g.

- devise.rb -> config.pepper
- secret_token.rb -> Application.config.secret_token
- capistrano -> deploy.rb
- ...

Adding config/****/* to .gitignore would not only prevent new developers from *bundle install, db:create, db:migrate, rails server* but also to keep the production config up to date if a new gem with an initializer is installed.

Another possibility would be add an **environment.yml** with sensitive config, like database.yml where sensitive configuration in the initializers will be overridden?

This will make it easy to get up and running after a clean checkout and the production environment will be easy to maintain.

Any ideas how to approach my problems above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually put "safe" data in these files, which will usually work for development purposes. But in production I symlink the files to another location with capistrano, like this:

```
invoke_command "ln -sf #{shared_path}/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
```

So in the production server I have a bunch of files that override the files in source control. I don't even work with a `database.yml.example`, just some sane default `database.yml` that the developers agree upon to use in development and test.

For individual settings, like API keys, I usually create a `config/settings.yml` and read them from inside the initializer:

```
SETTINGS = YAML.load(IO.read(Rails.root.join("config", "settings.yml")))
YourApp::Application.config.secret_token = SETTINGS["secret_token"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and it feels good that your solution is similar to my imaginary one. Are there any other sensitive settings in a vanilla rails site? I will give your solution a try, it's simple and I think it will fit my needs to start with.

Comment: I don't know how the symlink can work for you when you're running "cap deploy:migrations" since the are running against the release and not the current dir? I needed to change the symlink to >run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"< like the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449836/how-to-manage-rails-database-yml