# Postgres <=> Rails . How to auto-create a user from database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, rails-postgresql, pg

I am using PG for my rails4 application.

Every time I git clone to a new machine or clear my project, I have to keep creating the user for postgres before I get the app working again.

This is a problem when I share my code with designers etc and they have to unnecessarily get into details of setting up the db users and making them super users etc.

Is there a way I can automate this , given that I am using the PG gem and the Rails already know about the users I need from my database.yml

Comment: Why don't you write a simple shell script that anyone can run to generate the postgres user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this. `database.yml` doesn't belong in version control, see [How to manage Rails database.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449836/how-to-manage-rails-database-yml).

You should be storing a template file (I use `config/database.yml.example`) and each person who clones your app should copy the template file to `config/database.yml`, and add to it their *existing* database user and password, for connecting to their local development instance of Postgres.

Your designers should also have a single development user on their local machines, and it's up to them to place their credentials into `config/database.yml`.

There is no way to have Rails create database users for you, because it's supposed to be your job to tell Rails *existing* database user it should use. All your apps, in your development environment, should be using the same user.

Comment: I disagree; I think it's fine to have *development* and *test* sections of `database.yml` in version control. No sense in making devs jump through hoops for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `initdb` command with the `--auth-local trust` option right after PostgreSQL installation, it will bypass all future database user authentication:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8 --auth-local trust
```

Of course this would be a major security issue when used outside a development environment. But since you mentioned the specific need to have a quicker setup for people who work on the project, it seemed like it might be a possible approach in your case.

Answer (score -1):

@meagar is correct about keeping your passwords and keys out of version control, so definitely keep that advice in mind.

It's conventional these days to use environment variables to store login information, because that data is inherently tied to the environment you're running on. So you could, in fact, check `database.yml` into version control, provided you put in calls to environment variables, rather than the actual secrets.

For example, you could put something like `username: <%= ENV[DB_USER_DEV] %>` and `password: <%= ENV[DB_PASS_DEV] %>` in your `database.yml` file. Then, put `DB_USER_DEV=my_psql_username` and `DB_PASS_DEV=hashed_gibberish` into `~/.profile`.

With vagrant, I create the user and environment variables in the provisioning of the Vagrantfile for the base box. All our projects use the same base box, and adding those ENV vars to `database.yml` more or less automate everything in dev!